# Running a script multiple times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to run an SQL script as a job and I would like it to run twice when scheduled. How can I do that on the script below.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysindexes
           WHERE name = 'IgnoreList_Specification')
           DROP INDEX IgnoreList.IgnoreList_Specification
GO
CREATE INDEX IgnoreList_Specification ON IgnoreList
       (Specification)
       WITH  FILLFACTOR = 90 ON [PRIMARY]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysindexes
           WHERE name = 'IgnoreList_Custom')
           DROP INDEX IgnoreList.IgnoreList_Custom
GO
CREATE INDEX IgnoreList_Custom ON IgnoreList
       (Custom)
       WITH  FILLFACTOR = 90 ON [PRIMARY]
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysindexes
           WHERE name = 'IgnoreList_Custom1')
           DROP INDEX IgnoreList.IgnoreList_Custom1
GO
CREATE INDEX IgnoreList_Custom1 ON IgnoreList
       (Custom1)
       WITH  FILLFACTOR = 90 ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: umm...ctrl-c, ctrl-v?

Comment: Why would you like to create/drop/create the same index?
If you want to do it you could call the code twice.

Comment: Are you trying to do what the *Rebuild Index Task (Maintenance Plan)* is designed for?  Why twice?

Comment: @AlexK. For some reason when I run it once it doesn't run correctly

Comment: I think you should edit the question describing what happens when it fails as thats the problem that needs solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each batch you want to run twice, use GO 2. This will execute the batch twice

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

If you want to run the entire job twice, you can schedule one to run after the other finishes, or just duplicate the steps.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense

Comment: No worries @JohnMolina